# virtualenvwrapper: how to update project path?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I move a project folders I have to manually update the project path in the .project file to get the workon command to work. Is it possible to update the path automatically?

Comment: you can create a new virtualenv and copy your code

Answer (score 30):

According to the docs you can use [`setvirtualenvproject`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#setvirtualenvproject). This will automatically move you to the project folder if you use the `workon` command:

```
bono~$: setvirtualenvproject ~/.virtualenvs/your-virtual-env/ ~/path/to/your/project
```

Or, as beruic mentioned, it's easier to activate the environment and move to your desired working directory first. Please note that this not always work on my system, but it is a lot easier if it does work for you:

```
$ workon your-virtual-env
$ cd ~/path/to/your/project
$ setvirtualenvproject
```

In the future it might also be handy to specify the project path for the virtualenv on creation. You have to specify the project with the [`-a`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mkvirtualenv) flag.

> The -a option can be used to associate an existing project directory with the new environment.

You can use it something like this:

```
bono~$: cd ~/your/project
bono~$: mkvirtualenv my-project -a $(pwd)
```

The next time you use `workon` you will automatically be moved to your project directory.

## Alternative

---

If you want to automatically detect directory changes and set the correct virtualenvwrapper then and there you can have a look at [this post](https://justin.abrah.ms/python/virtualenv_wrapper_helper.html). It's a bit too expansive to go into detail here, but I think you can find what you're looking for there if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 14):

You can just activate your virtual environment, go to the folder you want as project folder and call `setvirtualenvproject`:

```
$ workon [your_project]
$ cd [desired_project_folder]
$ setvirtualenvproject
```

Then the current folder will be set as project folder in the current virtualenv.